# BackPress Issue when using buttonclick event in my adapter

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I'm using an adapter view and inside adapter a button click event for opening another activityB. When I'm pressing Back Button in my Activity B it re-opens Activity B for 7 times and then it goes back to my previous ActivityA where there exists my adapter View.It is like it runs my button click event in adapter view automatically when I'm pressing Back button.

Here is my Adapter Code:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{



View row = convertView;
if (row == null)
{
    row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.InventoryPreview, null, false);

}


TextView txtInventoryID = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryID);
    txtInventoryID.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemID;
TextView txtInventoryName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryName);
    txtInventoryName.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemName;
TextView txtInventoryPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtInventoryPrice);
    txtInventoryPrice.Text = mitems[position].InventoryItemPrice.Replace(",", ".");



Button ExtraBtn = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ExtrasBtn);

    ExtraBtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        try
        {

            mContext.StartActivity(typeof(ExtrasPreviewMain));//Here I open ActivityB.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(mContext, Convert.ToString(ex), ToastLength.Long);
            toast.Show();
        }

    };




return row;
```

}

And Here is My ActivityB Back Press:

```
 public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Layout.trans_right_in, Resource.Layout.trans_right_out);
    }
```

Also, i have disabled autofocus in my XML file. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that every time `GetView` is called the event handler for your button `Clicked` event is assigned. You never seem to un-assign it.

So one way to solve this is to only assign the click handler if `row == null`.

Another way is to not have a button and use the `ItemSelected` event instead on the ListView.